# Preg match question

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm sure someone already asked this question, but after searching for more than 1 hour on google, I decided to ask my question here.

I want to itterate over an array excisting of different strings/texts. 
These texts contain strings with both ##valuetoreplace## and #valuetoreplace#

I want to make to preg_matches:

```
$pattern = '/^#{1}+(\w+)+#{1}$/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $value, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
{
   // do something with the #values#
}
```

AND

```
$pattern = '/^#{2}+(\w+)+#{2}$/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $value, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
{
   //do something with the ##value##
}
```

This works great. 
Now my only problem is as follows:

When i have a string like

```
$valueToMatch = 'proceding text #value#';
```

My preg_match cant find my value anymore (as i used a ^ and a $).

Question: how can i find the `#value#` and the `##value##`, without having to worry if these words are in the middle of a (multi-line) value?

*In addition:
What i want is to find patterns and replace the #value# with a db value and a `##value##` with a array value. 
For example:

```
$thingsToReplace = 'Hello #firstname# #lastname#, 
How nice you joined ##namewebsite##.';
```

should be

```
'Hello John Doe, 
How nice you joined example.com.'
```

Comment: What do you mean with *without having to worry if these words are in the middle of a (multi-line) value*? Do you *want* to much across lines or not?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `/##([^#]+)##/` and `/#([^#]+)#/`, in that order.

Comment: I already tried this one. The only problem is. That in this case ##value## is correct too!, as #value# is part of [#]#value#[#]

Comment: In that case, run the regex that replaces `##valuetoreplace##` *first* so that those ones will be all gone, and *then* run the regex that replaces `#valuetoreplace#`. If you do it in that order, you won't have the problem you described above, because all the instances of `##valuetoreplace##` will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe nice to know for other visitors how i did it:

```
foreach($personalizeThis as $key => $value) 
{
   //Replace ##values##
   $patternIniData = '/#{2}+(\w+)#{2}/';
   $return = 'website'; //testdata
   $replacedIniData[$key] = preg_replace($patternIniData, $return, $value);

   //Replace #values#
   $pattern = '/#{1}+(\w+)#{1}/';  
   $return = 'ASD'; //testdata
   $replacedDbData[$key] = preg_replace($pattern, $return, $replacedIniData[$key]);
}
```

return $replacedDbData;